# how to check for null object returned in xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode, null

I have a NULL object returned from a JSON query string and I don't know how to check for it in an If statement. My syntax is below but I still don't seem to be able to trap for the `NULL` class (i.e., if nothing is returned then no text variable can be set therefore it MUST be a `NULL` class?), anyway, I need to check that the `@"BillingStreet"` has something in it and if not to avoid processing it (else the app crashes as it tries to set nothing to the text value of one of the `fields` in the `VC`):

```
- (void) tableView: (UITableView *)itemTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    NSDictionary *obj = [self.dataCustomerDetailRows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = [obj objectForKey:@"BillingStreet"] == nil ? @"0" : [obj objectForKey:@"BillingStreet"];
    NSLog(@"%@",text);
    if (text.class == NULL){
    } else {
        NSLog(@"no street");
        self.labelCustomerAddress.text = [obj objectForKey:@"BillingStreet"];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A JSON "null" value is converted to `[NSNull null]`, which you can check
for with

```
if (text == [NSNull null]) ...
```

because it is a *singleton*.

Alternatively, you can check if the object contains the expected type, i.e. a string:

```
NSString *text = [obj objectForKey:@"BillingStreet"];
if ([text isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    self.labelCustomerAddress.text = text;
} else {
    self.labelCustomerAddress.text = @"no street";
}
```

This is more robust in the case that a server sends bad data, e.g. a number or an array instead of a string.

Comment: Thanks Martin, tested and that works (I put this in: ' if (text == (id)[NSNull null] || text.length ==0 || [text isEqualToString:@"null"])'       I can across the answeer as well in this question, so I may have duplicated my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785124/exception-if-nil-or-null

Comment: I think this is more efficient as it removes the need for creating a string variable : 'if ([obj objectForKey:@"BillingStreet"] == (id)[NSNull null])'

Comment: @Bartley: No, assigning `text = [obj objectForKey:@"BillingStreet"]` is more efficient because it retrives the dictionary value only once.

Answer (score 6):

`text == nil ? @"0" : text`

or

`text ? text : @"0"`

But if you get it from JSON then you may get instance of `NSNull` class. In this case you should check

`text && ![text isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ? text : @"0"`